# Range of the real zeros of the polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was thinking for this problem:

Let $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$, where all $a_k$'s are real numbers.

Assume that $|a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-2}|+...+|a_0|≤1$.

Show that the real zeros of $f(x)$ lie in $[-1, 1]$.

I think it will be solved by using triangle inequality, but I can't figure it out.

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $x$ is a real root of $f$, with $|x|>1$. Then
\begin{align*}
|x^n| > |x^{n-1}| &\geq (|a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-2}|+...+|a_0|)|x|^{n-1} \\
& =|a_{n-1}||x|^{n-1}+|a_{n-2}||x|^{n-1}+...+|a_0||x|^{n-1}\\
& \geq |a_{n-1}||x|^{n-1}+|a_{n-2}||x|^{n-2}+...+|a_0|
\end{align*}

But because $-x^n = a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + ... + a_0$, one also has $$|x^n| \leq |a_{n-1}||x|^{n-1} + |a_{n-2}||x|^{n-2} + ... + |a_0|$$

Contradiction, and you are done.